# Java EE 6 release date

Tags: jakarta-ee

Java EE 6 looks exciting. It will include the Servlet 3.0 spec, EJB3.1 Lite, Profiles, JSF2.0 Restful API, JPA2.0 and the WebBeans.

I tried to google the scheduled release date for the platform but could not find anything official. Anyone? Or is it just the way it works? As soon as all the JCP expert groups finish the specs will it be official?

Comment: JEE6 is exciting, but I guess you would get more answers if you could ask one question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [JSR316](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=316) (JavaTM Platform, Enterprise Edition 6 ([Java EE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform,_Enterprise_Edition) 6) Specification) is, according to this very "Specification" page, "targeted to ship in 2008.".

Ahem.

If you compare their Stages with those of the previous Java EE (Java EE 5 in [JSR 244](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=244)), you will realize that:

- Java EE 6 is at the "Early Draft Review " stage finished in November 2008
- The number of months between Java EE 5 "Early Draft Review " and its final release was: 12 months (may 2005 to its final release in may 2006).

So here you go. I do not know if the parallel is accurate, but that is the only date you can guesstimate for now. Even though [InfoQ](http://www.infoq.com/news/2008/11/openejb-3.1-release) or [JavaOne200](http://technology.amis.nl/blog/3163/javaone-2008-lingo-keywords-recurring-themes-buzzwords-and-hype-terms)8 mentioned "early 2009" as a possible ship date, it might be a tiny bit later than that (like "Q4 2009"!)

Answer (score 0):

Robert Chinnici's [Blog](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/robc/) is a good place to look - originally they were shooting for JavaOne 2009 [release](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/robc/archive/2008/10/update_on_the_s.html), now it looks later than [that](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/robc/archive/2009/01/java_ee_6_platf_1.html).

My best guess is they'd be working very hard to have some sort of preview for JavaOne 2009 - with production release probably 6 months after - ie late 2009.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](http://www.internetnews.com/dev-news/article.php/3825056/Where+Is+Java+EE+6.htm), it's scheduled for the Fall of this year.