# When does PHP 5.4 get released

Tags: php

Hey Anyone know when php 5.4 will be released?

I heard it will have php-fpm built in.

Comment: not related to programming question

Comment: how is it not? you know php is a programming language right?

Comment: I would have voted to close, but there's precedent for "release date" questions staying open.

Comment: FPM built in is going to be sweet. Nginx FTW.

Comment: For all of you voting to close, then you'd better vote to close: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/440156/net-4-0-and-visual-studio-release-date
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3326852/ruby-on-rails-3-release-date
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/453436/jee6-release-date
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1746775/mysql-6-release-date
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2619894/mysql-6-0-release-date
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4615284/orbeon-3-9-release-date

Comment: Jason, "when will X be released"-type questions are generally frowned upon on SO. We don't know any more than you do, after a Google search. As for the other questions, go ahead and close them, you have our blessings.

Comment: go ahead and close it, i got my answer. thanks brock.

Comment: christ, you ask when the next version of visual studio will be released on SO and you get 70 freaking upvotes.  This guy asks about a php release and the question is closed as not being a real question.  I suppose if you asked a question about Steve Balmers penis size on SO you'd recieve 100 upvotes. wtf?

Comment: LOL Anthony, I love it! so true.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

php-fpm is included in PHP core [as of 5.3.3](http://php.net/ChangeLog-5.php#5.3.3).

Installation/configuration docs on the PHP website: http://us.php.net/manual/en/install.fpm.php

Comment: Thanks Brock. you truly are a king amongst men